How can i make something like the picture (the numbers in the axis dont matter)

I have made the outline but cant figure out how to fill with lines, heres the code.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)--(6,0);
    \draw [thick] (6,0)--(10,0);
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)--(0,7);
    \draw [thick] (0,7)--(0,10);
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)-- (-4,-4);
    \draw [thick](-4,-4)--(-7,-7);
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)--(3.14,-2.67);
    \draw (6,0) to [bend right] (0,7);
    \draw (0,7) to [bend right] (-4,-4);
    \draw (6,0) to [bend left] (-4,-4);
    \path[fill=gris];
    \draw [very thick] (-2.67,4) to [bend left] (3.14,-2.67);
    \draw [dashed](-2.67,4)-- (-2.67,-2.67);
    \draw [dashed](3.14,-2.67)-- (-2.67,-2.67);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

My mind is going towards specifying the boundary of the shaded area and using the shading library. You could also specify the curves exactly, but that would require knowing how to use the plot syntax: https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots

yeah i literally picked up latex two days ago i dunno how to do that :(, i will read the plot thingy and try to see if it works

welcome! can you complete your code so it can be compiled? you can use the patterns library to fill an area with lines.

Here is a way to do it.

The key is to draw one cyclic path first, and redraw the outer part later. The pattern appears to be small, because your drawing spans quite a range: try scaling it down manually, i.e. adapt the coordinates. See e.g. here the visual effect for smaller drawings.
Adjust opacity as needed: even no transparancy seems to work with the hatch pattern.
To close the cylce I needed to adjust the order of coordinates. Best try following one route only, e.g. introduce coordinates in counterclockwise direction.
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
...
    % ~~~ this seems to be the segment ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [dashed,opacity=.5,pattern=north east lines] 
        (-2.67,-2.67)coordinate(X) --  \vis{} --cycle ;

Splitting "one" path with several options into 1 closed and one open allows you to do the following and control appearance separately:
% ~~~ to redraw this segment later again ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\vis[0]{(-2.67,4) to [bend left]  (3.14,-2.67)}
...
% // draw the closed hatched area
    % ~~~ redraw the visible segment
    \draw[line width=3pt] \vis{};

OUTLOOK: If you set relevant coordinates, like (-2.67,-2.67)coordinate(X) you can reuse it later more easily:
    % ~~~ for later ~~~~
    \node[anchor=east] at (X) {just reuse this coordinate};

IF YOU develop each drawing in a separate file using the standalone class and compile them, you can use all those pdfs  like ordinary drawings in your main document, and place them more freely. See e.g. this example how to do it; yes, they remain vector graphics this way.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% ~~~ to redraw this segment later again ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\vis[0]{(-2.67,4) to [bend left]  (3.14,-2.67)}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)--(6,0);
    \draw [thick] (6,0)--(10,0);
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)--(0,7);
    \draw [thick] (0,7)--(0,10);
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)-- (-4,-4);
    \draw [thick](-4,-4)--(-7,-7);
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0)--(3.14,-2.67);
    \draw (6,0) to [bend right] (0,7);
    \draw (0,7) to [bend right] (-4,-4);
    \draw (6,0) to [bend left] (-4,-4);
    
    % ~~~ this seems to be the segment ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [dashed,opacity=.5,pattern=north east lines] 
        (-2.67,-2.67)coordinate(X) --  \vis{} --cycle ;
    % ~~~ redraw the visible segment
    \draw[line width=3pt] \vis{};
    
    % ~~~ for later ~~~~
    \node[anchor=east] at (X) {just reuse this coordinate};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


omg thank you so much!! and thanks for the tips :D
